Missing required parameter for update route laravel 11
I have an error

Missing required parameter for [Route: updatetransaksi] [URI: penjualan/update/{id}] [Missing parameter: id].

web code
route::get('/penjualan/edit/{id_penjualan}', [PenjualanController::class, 'edit']);
route::post('/penjualan/update/{id}', [PenjualanController::class, 'update'])->name('updatetransaksi');

controller code
public function edit(string $id_penjualan)
    {
        $penjualan = Penjualan::where('id_penjualan', $id_penjualan)->first();
        $penjualan = DetailPenjualan::with('Penjualan', 'Barang')->where('id_penjualan', $id_penjualan)->get();
        $penjualanData = Penjualan::with('pembeli', 'detailPenjualan.barang')->find($id_penjualan);
        $pembeli = Pembeli::find($id_penjualan);
        $barang = Barang::all();

        return view('penjualan.edit', compact('penjualan', 'penjualanData', 'pembeli', 'barang', 'id_penjualan'));
    }

public function update(Request $request, $id_penjualan)
    {}

view code
<form action="{{ url('updatetransaksi', ['id' => $id_penjualan]) }}" method="POST">

how to solve this error

Your controller method and route parameter don't match. You either change your route definition from this:
route::post('/penjualan/update/{id}', [PenjualanController::class, 'update'])->name('updatetransaksi')

to this:
route::post('/penjualan/update/{id_penjualan}', [PenjualanController::class, 'update'])->name('updatetransaksi')

or your controller function definition from this:
public function update(Request $request, $id_penjualan)

to this:
public function update(Request $request, $id)

Either way works fine.

In Form
<form action="{{ route('updatetransaksi', ['id' => $id_penjualan]) }}" method="POST">


use route() instead of url(). URL route won't automatically resolve named routes and their parameters

